# App rejected because of Data Storage - how do I get it to ignore all of my files in a folder?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud

I have an app that downloads a ton of photos and stores them in a subfolder of the Documents folder which was apparently fine until iOS 5.1

Now Apple is telling me I need to store them else where or somehow mark them as not for backup.  This is an app update so for most of my users the data will already exist in these subfolders.

How do I get iOS to skip all of the files in my subfolders of Documents or to skip a particular file in the Documents folder?

It would be a HUGE undertaking to move all of the files to the cache like they suggest.

I read this but I am no sure exactly where I am suppose to implement this:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html

Comment: How are a couple of `moveItemAtURL:toURL:error:` calls that move existing files to the Caches directory a huge undertaking? There is a high chance that you can't avoid doing that anyway, because the do-not-backup-flag does not work on iOS 5.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use NSFileNanager to list all the files, then call the function that is suggested in your like. Your code would be something like:

```
// From Apple FAQ
#import <sys/xattr.h>
- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
    assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [URL path]]);

    const char* filePath = [[URL path] fileSystemRepresentation];

    const char* attrName = "com.apple.MobileBackup";
    u_int8_t attrValue = 1;

    int result = setxattr(filePath, attrName, &attrValue, sizeof(attrValue), 0, 0);
    return result == 0;
}


- (void) addSkipBackupAttributeToItemsInFolder:(NSString*)folder
{
    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *dirContents = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:folder error:nil];

    for (int curFileIdx = 0; curFileIdx < [dirContents count]; ++curFileIdx)
    {
        NSString* curString = [folder stringByAppendingPathComponent:[dirContents objectAtIndex:curFileIdx]];
        NSURL* curFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:curString];
        [self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL: curFileUrl];
    }
}
```

And you will use this like that:

```
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    [self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemsInFolder:documentsDirectory];
```

Comment: Just applying the addSkipBackuopAttribute to the folder itself prevented anything inside that folder to be backed up so no need for the second method.

Comment: One question. We are stuck like you with the "do not backup" mark. And I am seeing that you've used in iOS 5.1 the method described by Apple to use in iOS 5.0.1, right? Because, I we can't get working the method that Apple says that we need to use in iOS 5.1. The files are not being marked, but if we use the method described for being used in iOS 5.0.1 the files are well marked. But.... Apple says that method is deprecated. How did you solved it?